# How to remove \n between the outputs of two echo commands?

Tags: shell, shell-script

I have a text file containing one file name in each line:

```
111_c4l5r120.png
123_c4l4r60.png
135_c4l4r180.png
147_c4l3r60.png
15_c4l1r120.png
...
```

I want to convert it in this shape:

```
111_c4l5r120.png 111
123_c4l4r60.png 123
135_c4l4r180.png 135
147_c4l3r60.png 147
15_c4l1r120.png 15
...
```

using this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line || [[  -n "$line"  ]]; do
   echo "$line" >> output.txt   
   echo "$line" | cut -d'_' -f 1 >> output.txt
done < "$1"
```

but, the result is:

```
111_c4l5r120.png 
111
123_c4l4r60.png 
123
135_c4l4r180.png 
135
147_c4l3r60.png 
147
15_c4l1r120.png 
15
...
```

How should I change my script to have the desire output?

Comment: Google finds better results, e.g., [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545538/how-do-i-join-pairs-of-consecutive-lines-in-a-large-file-1-million-lines-using).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unless you have a specific need to use the shell for this, [terdon's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/286846/86440) provides better alternatives.

Since you're using `bash` (as indicated in the script's shebang), you can use the `-n` option to echo:

```
echo -n "${line} " >> output.txt
echo "$line" | cut -d'_' -f 1 >> output.txt
```

Or you can use shell features to process the line without using `cut`:

```
echo "${line} ${line%%_*}" >> output.txt
```

(replacing both `echo` lines).

Alternatively, `printf` would do the trick too, works in any [POSIX shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html), and is generally better (see [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/86440) for details):

```
printf "%s " "${line}" >> output.txt
echo "$line" | cut -d'_' -f 1 >> output.txt
```

or

```
printf "%s %s\n" "${line}" "${line%%_*}" >> output.txt
```

(Strictly speaking, in plain `/bin/sh`, [`echo -n` isn't portable](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html). Since you're explicitly using `bash` it's OK here.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40658/discussion-on-answer-by-stephen-kitt-how-to-remove-n-between-the-outputs-of-two).

Answer (score 23):

Don't do this sort of thing in the shell! It is far more complex than necessary, prone to errors and far, far, slower. There are many tools designed for such text manipulation. For example, in `sed` (here assuming recent GNU or BSD implementations for `-E`):

```
$ sed -E 's/([^_]*).*/& \1/' file
111_c4l5r120.png 111
123_c4l4r60.png 123
135_c4l4r180.png 135
147_c4l3r60.png 147
15_c4l1r120.png 15
```

Or, for any `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/\([^_]*\).*/& \1/' file
111_c4l5r120.png 111
123_c4l4r60.png 123
135_c4l4r180.png 135
147_c4l3r60.png 147
15_c4l1r120.png 15
```

Perl:

```
$ perl -pe 's/(.+?)_.*/$& $1/' file
111_c4l5r120.png 111
123_c4l4r60.png 123
135_c4l4r180.png 135
147_c4l3r60.png 147
15_c4l1r120.png 15
```

awk:

```
$ awk -F_ '{print $0,$1}' file
111_c4l5r120.png 111
123_c4l4r60.png 123
135_c4l4r180.png 135
147_c4l3r60.png 147
15_c4l1r120.png 15
```

Comment: External utilities are not much better, though.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος yes they are. Several orders of magnitude faster, actually. The shell is just not very good at this sort of thing. A shell's main job is launching external utilities, after all. Compare the time taken by the OP's approach to that taken by any of the solutions here. Shell loops are very, very slow. If you need more convincing, read [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169765/22222).

Comment: In terms of portability, nope. In terms of speed, yes. Also, is @StéphaneChazelas your alias?

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος Θα 'θελα :) No, he just happens to have written 2 great answers that were relevant to the two comment threads. As for portability, with the (minor) exception of the perl approach which will only work on something like ~90% of *nix machines, all three solutions are portable and shell agnostic. Or, OK, you could always make the `sed` one into `sed 's/\([^_]*\).*/& \1/' file` for extra portability. Point is, you can count on `awk` and `sed` being there more than you can count on pretty much anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Here you are:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS='' read -r line || [[  -n "$line"  ]]; do
   echo "$line" `echo "$line" | cut -d'_' -f 1` >> output.txt
#   echo "$line" | cut -d'_' -f 1 >> output.txt
done < "$1"
```

Output:

```
$ rm -rf output.txt
$ ./test.sh 1.1; cat output.txt
111_c4l5r120.png 111
123_c4l4r60.png 123
135_c4l4r180.png 135
147_c4l3r60.png 147
15_c4l1r120.png 15
```